# Group concat if consecutive columns values are equal

Tags: mysql, grouping, group-concat

How to group `concat` rows when particular column consicitive values are equal?

Table values 
|---------------|
| id    | msg     |
|---------------|
| 1 | a           |
|---------------|
| 2 | b           |
| --------------|
| 2 | c           |
|---------------|
| 1 | b           |
|---------------|
| 1 | d           |
|---------------|

Expected Out Put

|---------------|
| id    | msg     |
|---------------|
| 1 | a            |
|---------------|
| 2 | b,c         |
| --------------|
| 1 | b.d         |
|---------------|

Any help is much appreciated :)

Thank You